# Is it possible to auto config IPv6 address on Debian interface

Tags: networking, debian, ipv6

I got a /64 from my VPS provider, I used to have on-link IPv6 addresses which I used to generate using their control panel, now they give routed subnet, which is something new to me. I figured out how to add IPv6 manually now but was thinking if this can be auto configured, like if I define the IPv6 address in Apache virtual host and it will start working without manually adding the address in the interface file.

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
netmask 255.255.255.0
 
gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
iface eth0 inet6 static
    address 2604:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::
    netmask 64

    gateway 2604:xxxx:xxxx:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001

iface eth0 inet6 static
    address 2604:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx
iface eth0 inet6 static
    address 2604:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx
iface eth0 inet6 static
    address 2604:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx
iface eth0 inet6 static
    address 2604:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx
iface eth0 inet6 static
    address 2604:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx
iface eth0 inet6 static
    address 2604:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

We have two type Configuration IP , Static and auto (DHCP) your DHCP server must be capable to assign IPV6 to your client

for configured Manuel based on other app like setting in apache virtual host you need write script and set in Manuel in setting like configuration file per interface in
/etc/network/interfaces.d/ directory instead of /etc/network/interfaces configuration for assign permanent

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
iface eth0 inet6 static

netmask 64

up /sbin/ifconfig eth0 inet6 add 2604:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/64
```

works now.